# Navigate to detail page using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a component which is creating opportunity record and I want after successfull creation it redirects to the newly created opportunity detail page.

Opportunity creation is working fine but after creation it is not redirecting to the detail page. It throws the error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
>   $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
>   Callback failed: apex://createOpp/ACTION$CreateOpportunity Failing
>   descriptor: {c:createNewOppCmp}

Controller.JS:

```
({
save : function(component, event, helper) {
    var OpptyObj = component.get("v.Oppty");

    var action = component.get("c.CreateOpportunity");

    action.setParams({
        Oppty : OpptyObj 
    });

    action.setCallback(this,function(res){

        var oppId = res.getReturnValue();
        alert(oppId);
          var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
           //   "url": "https://ashuforce-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/"+oppId+" "
                "url" : "/006/o"+oppId
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
    });

  $A.enqueueAction(action);

} })
```

Not sure why `e.force:navigateToURL` is not working properly, what I am missing here?

Comment: apex controller returning the id of newly created record, I can see in the alert.

Comment: Nopes, that's the complete one which I am getting everytime.

Comment: if you completely remove the navigation event related code, do you still get the error?

Comment: No, if I remove then it works fine without any error.

Comment: alert(oppId); This part is working? So do you recieve oppId and alert shows it?

Answer (score 3):

Use new lightning:navigation component for that.
Just add it to your component:

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navigation"/>
```

and in method navigate to detail page:

```
    component.find("navigation")
    .navigate({
        "type" : "standard__recordPage",
        "attributes": {
            "recordId"      : recordId,
            "actionName"    : actionName ? actionName : "view"   //clone, edit, view
        }
    }, true);
```

ps. you need to change API version to 43 in your component.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: are you sure that you're recieving response with id of newly created opportunity?

I would recommend to check the state of the response before trying to navigate to created record, and then use `e.force:navigateToSObject`

```
var state = res.getState();
if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
    var oppId = res.getReturnValue();
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
        "recordId": oppId
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```

Comment: Yes, opportunity is creating successfully also I am getting the Id of the newly created opportunity record in the JS controller but getting the same error in navigating.

Comment: Could you please provide your apex backend code? From the description of the error I think something is wrong there and not in the navigation itself.